# How to read Mojo name inside the custom maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I created a custom maven plugin and want to read the name of the goal within the code.

@Mojo(name="wite-to-file")

```
@Mojo(name="write-to-file")

public class CustomPlugin{

public void execute(){

Annotation[] annotations = this.getClass().getAnnotations();

annotations[0].toString() // this does not return the value of the Mojo.

}

}

When maven plugin's execute method gets called, Is there a way to access the current goal name? or the name of the Mojo?

I tried annotations but could not read the value of Mojo.
```

Comment: I guess you need to extend `AbstractMojo` class as well.

Comment: The extend to `AbstractMojo` is correct but why do you need to get the goal name? You have defined it via `@Mojo(name="...")`?

Answer (score 2):

you can inject `mojoExecution` and retrieve the goal name from it:

```
@Mojo(name="write-to-file")
public class CustomPlugin {

  @Parameter(defaultValue = "${mojoExecution}")
  protected MojoExecution mojoExecution;

  public void execute(){
    mojoExecution.getMojoDescriptor().getGoal() // this returns the value of the Mojo name `write-to-file`.
  }

}
```

Comment: Works fine, thx. I had to add a dependency to `org.apache.maven:maven-core` to find the `MojoExecution` type.

Comment: Even me, as a Maven Core developer appricate this answer since it helped me at lot to solve a problem here!